# Assigning Presence statuses by logic inside Omni-Channel flow

Tags: omnichannel, public-group

So... I have a preference so that I can route cases to agents based on public group membership, and this group membership would assign agents the correct Presence status based on what public group they belong to.  Is this possible?  I'm not sure -  based on the existing documentation.
My use case is as follows:
Customer support Team 1 handles billing cases and Customer support Team 2 handles tech support cases.  Users in Team 1 are billing specialists and are part of the Public Group **Billing**. These users have access to the Presence Status **Available - Billing support** and  users in Team 2 are tech support specialists and are part of the Public Group **Tech Support** and have access to the Presence Status **Available - Tech support**

Is there a way to use an Omni-Channel flow to assign these statuses programmatically?